# Cannot get all subject from student and grade with mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I would like to select `grade_point` and `grade_name` from table grade which according to mark in table exam, so my expectation is that if mark in table exam are between `grade_mark_from` and `grade_mark_up` it will list all and return `grade_name` and `grade_point` of student.

Table  Exam:

[image]

Table Subject: 
[image]

Table Exam result :
[image]

Table Grade :

[image]

Here is my query :

```
select s.subject_name, ex.exam_result_total_mark as Score, g.grade_name
from  stm_grade as g, stm_exam_result as ex
inner join stm_exam as e
on ex.exam_result_using_exam_id = e.exam_id
inner join stm_subject as s
on s.subject_id = ex.exam_result_using_subject_id
inner join stm_student_basic_info as st
on st.student_basic_info_id = ex.exam_result_using_student_basic_info_id
where ex.exam_result_using_exam_id = 2 and
      ex.exam_result_using_student_basic_info_id = 8 and
      ex.exam_result_total_mark between g.grade_mark_from and g.grade_mark_upto
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Is your query not working? Or not returning all the information? About students? About exams?...